# Bot Framework version 4: changes in botchat.cs,styles.css and botchat.js as compared to version 3

Tags: javascript, c#, css, botframework

We are currently working on migrating the existing chatbot to version 4. The botcode has been hosted on a customised website and the bot template is an older one.

Kindly help me with changes to be implemented with respect to the styling and scripting in the website so that it stays compatible with C# bot v4. What all changes have to be done as compared to v3 or previous?

Existing Scripts folder:
[Scripts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UZnZK.png) This is the screenshot of the existing scripts folder

Existing Content Folder:
[Content](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1rUlD.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Webchat v3 is compatible with Bot using SDK v4, so there's no need to implement changes if your aim is only to migrate your bot to v4 (and not the webchat to v4).

Those versionings may look similar but these are different products.

So to summarize:

- Webchat v3 is ok with bot v3 or v4
- Webchat v4 is ok with bot v3 or v4